# Convert hex string back to string

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have a string which has a character I would like to replace.

The character has a hex value of `96` and I would like to replace that character with a hex value of `2D`.  I tried to do a simple replace on the string but it didn't work because for some reason it doesn't recognize the char.  And whenever I print it out it just prints a blank value:

```
byte testByte = byte.Parse("96", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
char testChar = Convert.ToChar(testByte);  // when I print this its just a blank char
```

So, I moved on and converted the entire string into hex, but am not sure how to convert the hex value string back to string.  Here's what I have:

```
// using windows 1252 encoding
System.Text.Encoding windows1252Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
byte[] myByte = windows1252Encoding.GetBytes(myString);
var myHexString = BitConverter.ToString(myByte);

myHexString = myHexString .Replace("96", "2D");
```

so at this point I have replaced the hex value 96 to 2D, but how do I convert this hex value string back to string?  Any help would be great!

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the character has a hex value of 96"? Do you mean it's U+0096?

Comment: Really? That sounds very odd to me - where has this string come from? It would really help if you'd give more context.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *actually* trying to replace U+0096 with U+002D, you can use:

```
text = text.Replace("\u0096", "\u002d");
```

Note that U+0096 is "start of guarded area" though. If you actually mean "the value that is encoded in Windows 1252 as 96" then you might want:

```
text = text.Replace("\u2020", "\u002d");
```

(Based on the [Wikipedia cp 1252 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which shows 0x96 mapping to U+2020.)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace one character with the other. You can use the `\x` escape code to use a character code in hex to specify a character:

```
s = s.Replace('\x96', '\x2d');
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend using `\u` instead of `\x` - the fact that the latter is variable-length make is brittle.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's a good point, and I would understand it used in a string, but a character literal can only contain exactly one character, so the code can't be misinterpreted by the compiler as being something else. In that case you would get a compilation error instead.